# Jenkins - Master Slave set up questions

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

I followed tutorial to get Jenkins set up on Windows.

What i have is:

> Jenkins running with recommend plugins installed
>
> Jenkins URL changed to http:// my ipv4:8080/
>
> A project with a simple command [echo hi]

For nodes i currently have just the Master node which is tied to my main PC

My goal is have one computer send a command to all the slave PC's so they run a python script i created.

I create a windows VM and connected to the Jenkins server. I logged in with the admin account and created a new node.

[image]

I cant find anything useful to help me figure out what to put in launch command. When i launch my node on the VM without the launch command specified, it fails to launch.

Is the batch script i wrote in the project, what's sent to all the slave machines or do I have this all wrong?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I got it working thanks to the answer posted here. I wrote up a doc on how i got Jenkins working from installation to deployment. There are other resources out there but i hope this will help someone.

[Jenkins Master/Agent Setup](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1g1gRJeUeEWoaZy5381i2a4vNEEhMDRTrt5HssrZgOdY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I see people online who have more than two launch methods.
Jenkins only gives me the options:
"Launch slave agents via SSH" and "Launch agent via execution of command on the master"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the option **Launch slave agents via Java Web Start** you should specify the TCP port for slaves. 
It is done through Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > TCP port for JNLP agents. You can select fixed port 50000.   More info [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows).

Comment: Thanks that worked for me!
**NOTE** If anyone else new has this issue as well: Jenkins has running into an access denied issue when trying to create it a windows service. In the Jenkins folder that was made on the slave, open CMD as admin and navigate to the folder. if the exe jenkins-slave is in their run the command 

jekins-slave.exe install 

and it should work